# What can a translation of $y=x-e$ do to bring a polynomial into a depressed form?

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations, roots, quadratics, radicals

I am in the middle of writing an essay for my Using Radicals to Solve module, and I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I cannot find any answers for this anywhere so any help would be appreciated!

All I have so far is the definition of a depressed polynomial and the advantages of the depressing process.

I can't seem to figure out what effect the translation $y=x-e$ will have on higher degree polynomials, and why that would be helpful when solving them

**Any advice would be so appreciated!**

Comment: Did you search already? See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Depressed_Polynomial) for a definition. Why do you want to apply $y=x-e$? There is no context. Is $e=\exp(1)$? What exactly do you want to do? Give an example!

Answer (score 1):

A general answer could be : having one term less, one has one parameter less to cope with.

Let us give an illustration. Let us consider the general 3rd degree polynomial :

$$x^3+ax^2+bx+c$$

vs. its depressed form, traditionaly written :

$$x^3+px+q$$

In the first case, the discriminant is

$$a^2b^2+18abc-4b^3-4a^3c-27c^2$$

whereas in the second case it is plainly :

$$-(4p^3+27q^2).$$

(Let us recall that the sign of the discriminant of a third degree polynomial indicates if it has 1 or 3 real roots).